# draw in canvas only in visible area

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, viewport

I am in the middle of development of simple mini game and i started to notice some performance drops. Game is made the way that you have big room (canvas) that has `5000 x 5000` size and player is equipped with viewport camera that he can move on mouse drag. Now the problem is that if i am drawing 2000 objects for entire room, it causes significant performance drop. I was thinking if there is a way to only draw objects that are visible in your current camera area, not in entire room that player obviously doesn't see.

I tried to divide the room on sectors (regions) but that didnt work very well. Maybe someone has some thoughts on the subject.

This is rendering code for largest quantity of objects:

```
for(var i = 0; i < game.objects.stars.pool.length; i++) {
    var current = game.objects.stars.pool[i];
    game.components.star.apply(i);
    game.mechanics.draw.circle(current.x, current.y, current.r);
}
```

What can be done to this to improve the performance in the way i described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered this kind of problem and i solved it this way:

```
var in_viewport = function(x, y, margin) {
    if(
        x >= cam.x - margin &&
        x <= cam.x + cam.w + margin &&
        y >= cam.y - margin &&
        y <= cam.y + cam.h + margin
    ) {
       return true;
    }

    return false;
};
```

It could be implemented into your logic like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < game.objects.stars.pool.length; i++) {
    var current = game.objects.stars.pool[i];
    if( in_viewport(current.x, current.y, 100) === true ) {
        game.components.star.apply(i);
        game.mechanics.draw.circle(current.x, current.y, current.r);
    }
}
```

Now few words of explanation:

Margin parameter is recommended to be set to `100`, as it will help smooth the problem of "things show up out of the blue". It will simply render objects in range of `100` outside bounds of your camera, therefore even if you quickly move your camera, things should be already there, yet performance should be in very good place.

`cam.x`, `cam.y`, `cam.w`, `cam.h` inside of `in_viewport` function should be altered to match your camera object naming, in case if you already have your right and bottom bound inside camera object, you can just replace `x + w` and `y + h` with right parameters.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to check whether current object is within the bounds and only draw it if it is, so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < game.objects.stars.pool.length; i++) {
    var current = game.objects.stars.pool[i];
    if (withinBounds(current)){
        game.components.star.apply(i);
        game.mechanics.draw.circle(current.x, current.y, current.r);    
    }
}

function withinBounds(gameObject){
    if (gameObject.x + gameObject.r < viewPort.x && viewPort.x - gameObject.r > viewPort.x + viewPort.width) {
        if ( gameObject.y + gameObject.r < viewPort.y && gameObject.y - gameObject.y > viewPort.y + viewPort.height){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

where viewport is in relation to your 5000 by 5000 area.

This is without seeing all of your code, so you might need to adjust for your datatypes.